# How to change order status by custom module in Magento CE 1.7?

Tags: php, magento

I want to create a magento admin module which loads all the orders. And when the user selects an order it will show the order status. The user can change that order status. Any suggesions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by user you mean somebody with access to Backoffice, you can add new statuses in XML configuration files: http://blog.decryptweb.com/order-state-status-magento/

If you want to have it on Front office, you need to write new module, and remember, that you need also to check from which status user can change, that he will not change "Completed" to something else and you'll send products twice in fact.

**Update:** In Enterprise Edition there is also table for statuses and states AFAIK.